# COLOR DETECTION-FORMAT TYPE

Tags: python, color-detection

What is the meaning and use of this line:

```
print("The type of this input is {}".format(type(image)))
```

Comment: The line is quite simple. What is unclear about it?

Comment: That line prints the type of the object referenced by `image`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This line simply prints the data type of the value/object held by the variable `image`.

Comment: Please accept/upvote the answer if it was helpful, so others can refer to it as well! Thanks :)